# PHPExcel - Biblioteca converte automaticamente a notação da data ao importar planilha Excel, de dd/mm/aaaa muda para mm/dd/aaaa

Tags: php, microsoft-excel, data, phpexcel

Estou passando por um problema que já está me deixando careca..

Em uma determinada parte de uma aplicação, preciso importar os dados do usuário através de uma planilha Excel, para isso estou usando a biblioteca PHPExcel.

Porém, quando edito as informações no Ms Excel, ao importar, o PHPExcel muda a notação da data, misteriosamente.

Ex: Eu insiro a seguinte data na planilha, 10/07/2015 (dd/mm/aaaa), e ao importar a data fica 07/10/2015 (mm/dd/aaaa).

Este problema acontecia no Libre Office Calc, porém formatei a coluna da data para a notação dd/mm/aaaa, e as informações são importadas normalmente. Já no Ms Excel isso não resolve.

Já criei diversos filtros com o PHP para tratar este tipo de "erro" mas nunca dá certo...

Alguém já passou por isso? Alguma ideia do que fazer?

Muito Obrigado!!

Comment: A data informada no Excel será convertida para uma sequencia numérica. Por exemplo: 01/09/2015 = 42248. Não consegui compreender o motivo disso também, alguém com mais experiencia poderá ajudar a entender esse formato. Bem, minha solução foi colocar a seguinte linha no arquivo de importação que chama o PHPexcel.

$val = date('d/m/Y', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP( $cell->getValue() ) );

Veja se isso dará certo com você.

Comment: A data deve ser exportada (pelo PHP) no formato americano (Y-m-d). No excel, ele costuma compreender e colocar no formato do sistema. Mas, caso isso não ocorra automaticamente, basta formatar a celula